# Can't set Image.file to Circular Avatar in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to use Circular Avatar in my design. however i want to set the image based on a file chosen by the User in their gallery. this image is set to:

```
File _imageUpload;
```

This loads properly if i use a container with Image.file

However, CircularAvatar wont accept it as part of the backgroundImage property.

am i meant to convert the file to another file type before assigning it to the Circular Avatar?

Comment: Share some code including `CircularAvatar` widget, to be obviouse your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. In circular avatar you should not use `Image.file`. instead you should be using `FileImage`

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 57,
                          backgroundColor: Color(0xff476cfb),
                          child: ClipOval(
                            child: new SizedBox(
                              width: 100.0,
                              height: 100.0,
                              child: (_image != null)
                                  ? Image.file(
                                      _image,
                                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                    )
                                  : Image.network(
                                      "Any Url from the internet to display image",
                                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                    ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Image.file`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.file.html) for showing a local photo

```
Image.file(_imageUpload)
```